# Python MongoDB retrieve value of ISODate field

Tags: python, mongodb

I am writing a script in python that will query a MongoDB database, parse the results in a format that can be imported into a relational database.

The data is stored in an associative array. I am able to query most of the fields by using dot notation such as $status.state.

Issue:

The issue is that the field $last_seen ISODate is not returning a value when attempting to use dot notation.

```
        # Last seen dot notation does not return a value
        "u_updated_timestamp": "$last_seen.date"
```

Here is the data structure:

```
{
    "status" : {
        "state" : "up",
    },
    "addresses" : {
        "ipv4" : "192.168.1.1"
    },
    "last_seen" : ISODate("2016-04-29T14:06:17.441Z")
}
```

Here is the code that I am starting with. All of the other fields are returnign in the correct format. However, the last_seen ISO date field is not returning any value at all. What other steps are required in order to retrieve the value?

I tried $dateToString but it did not work (we are running pymongo 2.7).

```
computers = db['computer'].aggregate([
        {"$project" : { 
                "u_ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4",
                "u_status": "$status.state",
                # Last seen dot notation does not return a value
                "u_updated_timestamp": "$last_seen.date"
        }}
])
```

I also tried simply $last_seen but that returns key and value, I only need the value.

UPDATE: The desired format is flexible. It could be a unix timestamp or mm-dd-yyyy. Any format would be acceptable. The main issue is that there is no date value being returned at all with this query as it stands currently.

Comment: What is the expected date format you require? Can you show with an example?

Comment: The desired format is flexible. It could be a unix timestamp or mm-dd-yyyy. Any format would be acceptable. The main issue is that there is no date value being returned at all with this query as it stands currently. Thank you for helping.

Comment: You don't need to append the `.date` to the field, just return as it is e.g. `{"$project" : { "u_updated_timestamp": "$last_seen" } }` or if you need to format the date `{"$project" : { "u_updated_timestamp": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$last_seen" } } } }` which is available in MongoDB >= 3.0

Comment: Thank you, I tried returning as you described but it returns in this format:

{"$date":1461947391779}

I need to return the value only... so, is there a way to parse it further?

I am using mongodb 2.x so I am unable to use $dateToString. Thanks very much.